# How do I set the cache size of FirebaseDatabase in the new FirebaseDatabase API for Android?

Tags: android, caching, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I set the cache size of FirebaseDatabase in the new FirebaseDatabase API for Android?

I am just updating my legacy code to the new version, the old setup would be:

```
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    Config config = Firebase.getDefaultConfig();
    config.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    config.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(50 * 1000 * 1000);
    Firebase.setDefaultConfig(config);
```

The new code as described in documentations is only

```
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

But class FirebaseDatabase does not have a method like `setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes()` as described in this reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase
The new documentation states that the default size is 10Mb, but it does not tell me where to change this default value.

Comment: There is no method to set the size of the persistent cache in the 3.x SDK at the moment. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(long)) method. I don't know when this was added, though.

Answer (score 0):

This line works for me to set persistence cache size.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(50 * 1000 * 1000);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#public-synchronized-void-setpersistencecachesizebytes-long-cachesizeinbytes

This documentation will help to set cache size of firebase database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).